# Negative top vs negative left for visually hiding elements

Tags: css

The conventional way to visually hide something, but allow screenreaders to see it, is `left: -9999px`.

Why not `top: -9999px`?

Technically there are cases where someone could see something that's positioned way over to the left (eg a giant screen, or just zooming out really far). But a browser never lets you see above the top of the body. So isn't negative `top` better? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the user can see it as it will be in the source either way

Comment: ...? i'm talking about content intended for screenreaders

Comment: You said if the user zooms out really far? Either way if it is just plain text it doesnt matter.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't matter? It matters if it's visible

Comment: I mean if the user was to view the source code or use developer tools in their browser then they will be able to view the content no matter where you position it.

Comment: I don't care if someone can read it in my source code... what do you think I'm trying to do here?

Comment: i'm just talking about hiding things visually but keeping them on the DOM so they are available for other purposes (like screenreader access, or taking measurements, etc). do you think I'm talking about securing sensitive info? i wouldn't do that by hiding it with css...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [site](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) explains it nicely:

> It is sometimes recommended to position content using left:0px;
>   top:-500px (or similar). While this works by positioning the content
>   above the top of the page, if the hidden element contains a link or
>   form element, upon receiving keyboard focus, the browser attempts to
>   scroll to the element - thus scrolling the browser to the top of the
>   page. This could result in confusion for sighted keyboard users. By
>   positioning directly to the left, the browser will not scroll to the
>   top of the page. It should be noted that because links and form
>   elements provide functionality, they should rarely be hidden from
>   sighted users. Sighted users will not be able to see which element
>   currently has focus because it is hidden off-screen.

So in a nutshell, hiding content by moving it above the top of the page, as opposed to beyond the left edge, has the potential of causing a jump during navigation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new method for hiding content using the CSS clip property. The CSS clip property lets you specify the dimensions of an absolutely position element using top, right, bottom, and left values, which creates a box container for the element. By setting all the values to 0px, you can hide the element.

```
.hidden { 
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px 0px 0px 0px);
}
```

However, rending may vary depending on the browser. This method is credited to Jeff Burnz. You can read his article - [Using CSS clip as an Accessible Method of Hiding Content](http://adaptivethemes.com/using-css-clip-as-an-accessible-method-of-hiding-content).